# Problem creating nested JSON with python from csv with columns without value

Tags: python, json, csv, nested

Thanks in advance for helping.
I have a csv file with the following structure:

```
group1,group2,group3,name,info
General,Nation,,Phil,info1
General,Nation,,Karen,info2
General,Municipality,,Bill,info3
General,Municipality,,Paul,info4
Specific,Province,,Patrick,info5
Specific,Province,,Maikel,info6
Specific,Province,Governance,Mike,info7
Specific,Province,Governance,Luke,info8
Specific,District,,Maria,info9
Specific,District,,David,info10
```

I need a nested JSON for use in D3 or amcharts. 
With the python script on this page (https://github.com/hettmett/csv_to_json) I could create a nested JSON.

The results looks like this:

```
[
   {
      "name" : "General",
      "children" : [
         {
            "name" : "Nation",
            "children" : [
               {
                  "name" : "",
                  "children" : [
                     {
                        "name" : "Phil",
                        "children" : [
                           {
                              "name" : "info1"
                           }
                        ]
                     },
                     {
                        "name" : "Karen",
                        "children" : [
                           {
                              "name" : "info2"
                           }
                        ]
                     }
                  ]
               }
            ]
         },
         {
            "name" : "Municipality",
            "children" : [
               {
                  "name" : "",
                  "children" : [
                     {
                        "name" : "Bill",
                        "children" : [
                           {
                              "name" : "info3"
                           }
                        ]
                     },
                     {
                        "name" : "Paul",
                        "children" : [
                           {
                              "name" : "info4"
                           }
                        ]
                     }
                  ]
               }
            ]
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "name" : "Specific",
      "children" : [
         {
            "name" : "Province",
            "children" : [
               {
                  "name" : "",
                  "children" : [
                     {
                        "name" : "Patrick",
                        "children" : [
                           {
                              "name" : "info5"
                           }
                        ]
                     },
                     {
                        "name" : "Maikel",
                        "children" : [
                           {
                              "name" : "info6"
                           }
                        ]
                     }
                  ]
               },
               {
                  "name" : "Governance",
                  "children" : [
                     {
                        "name" : "Mike",
                        "children" : [
                           {
                              "name" : "info7"
                           }
                        ]
                     },
                     {
                        "name" : "Luke",
                        "children" : [
                           {
                              "name" : "info8"
                           }
                        ]
                     }
                  ]
               }
            ]
         },
         {
            "name" : "District",
            "children" : [
               {
                  "name" : "",
                  "children" : [
                     {
                        "name" : "Maria",
                        "children" : [
                           {
                              "name" : "info9"
                           }
                        ]
                     },
                     {
                        "name" : "David",
                        "children" : [
                           {
                              "name" : "info10"
                           }
                        ]
                     }
                  ]
               }
            ]
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

However it is not exactly what I need. The problem is that some of the columns do not have a value and therefore no child should be included in de nested JSON. 
Like this:

```
"name": "Overview",
  "children": [{
      "name": "General", 
          "children": [
              { "name": "Nation",
                  "children": [
                      {"name": "Phil", "info": "info1"},
                      {"name": "Karen", "info": "info2"} 
                  ]
              },
              { "name": "Municipality",
                  "children": [
                      {"name": "Bill", "info": "info3"},
                      {"name": "Paul", "info": "info4"} 
                  ]        
              }
          ]


}, 
{
      "name": "Specific", 
          "children": [
              { "name": "Province",
                  "children": [
                      {"name": "Patrick", "info": "info5"},
                      {"name": "Maikel", "info": "info6"},
                      {"name": "Governance",
                          "children": [
                              {"name": "Mike", "info": "info7"},
                              {"name": "Luke", "info": "info8"}
                          ]
                      }
                  ]
              },
              { "name": "District",
                  "children": [
                      {"name": "Maria", "info": "info9"},
                      {"name": "David", "info": "info10"} 
                  ]        
              }
          ]
}
]
```

Hope someone can help.

Kind regards
Stefan

Comment: Do the empty cells appear in just one column or can it happen in every column?

Comment: Empty cells can not appear in the first column (group1), and not in the columns name and info. In the other columns (group2 and group3) empty cells can appear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are actually two meaningful differences between your "ideal" result and the result given from the script:

1. The removal of empty strings (as you noted).
2. The last child is formatted as: `{"name": "xxxxx", "info": "yyyyy"}` rather than `{"name": "xxxxx", "children": [{"name": "yyyyy"}]}`.

So we can solve both of those problems:

Assuming you've defined `js_objs` as the result of the [csv-to-json](https://github.com/hettmett/csv_to_json) library you mentioned above.

```py
from copy import deepcopy


def remove_empties(children):
    """Just removes the empty name string levels."""
    for i, js in enumerate(children):
        if js['name'] == '':
            children.pop(i)
            if 'children' in js:
                for child_js in js['children'][::-1]:
                    children.insert(i, child_js)
            if i < len(children):
                js = children[i]
            else:
                raise StopIteration('popped off a cap')
    for i, js in enumerate(children):
        if 'children' in js:
            js['children'] = remove_empties(js['children'])
    return children


def parse_last_child(js):
    """Looks for the last child and formats that one correctly"""
    if 'children' not in js:
        print(js)
        raise ValueError('malformed js')
    if len(js['children']) == 1 and 'children' not in js['children'][0]:
        js['info'] = js.pop('children')[0]['name']
    else:
        js['children'] = [parse_last_child(j) for j in js['children']]
    return js


accumulator = deepcopy(js_objs)  # so we can compare against the original
non_empties = remove_empties(accumulator)
results = [parse_last_child(x) for x in non_empties]
```

And the results I get are...

```py
[{'name': 'General',
  'children': [{'name': 'Nation',
    'children': [{'name': 'Phil', 'info': 'info1'},
     {'name': 'Karen', 'info': 'info2'}]},
   {'name': 'Municipality',
    'children': [{'name': 'Bill', 'info': 'info3'},
     {'name': 'Paul', 'info': 'info4'}]}]},
 {'name': 'Specific',
  'children': [{'name': 'Province',
    'children': [{'name': 'Patrick', 'info': 'info5'},
     {'name': 'Maikel', 'info': 'info6'},
     {'name': 'Governance',
      'children': [{'name': 'Mike', 'info': 'info7'},
       {'name': 'Luke', 'info': 'info8'}]}]},
   {'name': 'District',
    'children': [{'name': 'Maria', 'info': 'info9'},
     {'name': 'David', 'info': 'info10'}]}]}]
```

Note:
This will work as long as your json objects aren't too deep. Otherwise you'll hit the recursion depth.

Just to clarify, in this case:

```py
js_objs = [
   {
      "name" : "General",
      "children" : [
         {
            "name" : "Nation",
            "children" : [
               {
                  "name" : "",
                  "children" : [
                     {
                        "name" : "Phil",
                        "children" : [
                           {
                              "name" : "info1"
                           }
                        ]
                     },
                     {
                        "name" : "Karen",
                        "children" : [
                           {
                              "name" : "info2"
                           }
                        ]
                     }
                  ]
               }
            ]
         },
         {
            "name" : "Municipality",
            "children" : [
               {
                  "name" : "",
                  "children" : [
                     {
                        "name" : "Bill",
                        "children" : [
                           {
                              "name" : "info3"
                           }
                        ]
                     },
                     {
                        "name" : "Paul",
                        "children" : [
                           {
                              "name" : "info4"
                           }
                        ]
                     }
                  ]
               }
            ]
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "name" : "Specific",
      "children" : [
         {
            "name" : "Province",
            "children" : [
               {
                  "name" : "",
                  "children" : [
                     {
                        "name" : "Patrick",
                        "children" : [
                           {
                              "name" : "info5"
                           }
                        ]
                     },
                     {
                        "name" : "Maikel",
                        "children" : [
                           {
                              "name" : "info6"
                           }
                        ]
                     }
                  ]
               },
               {
                  "name" : "Governance",
                  "children" : [
                     {
                        "name" : "Mike",
                        "children" : [
                           {
                              "name" : "info7"
                           }
                        ]
                     },
                     {
                        "name" : "Luke",
                        "children" : [
                           {
                              "name" : "info8"
                           }
                        ]
                     }
                  ]
               }
            ]
         },
         {
            "name" : "District",
            "children" : [
               {
                  "name" : "",
                  "children" : [
                     {
                        "name" : "Maria",
                        "children" : [
                           {
                              "name" : "info9"
                           }
                        ]
                     },
                     {
                        "name" : "David",
                        "children" : [
                           {
                              "name" : "info10"
                           }
                        ]
                     }
                  ]
               }
            ]
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! This seems the result I need. However I am not sure how to correctly import the csv-file? Can you please add this to the answer? I also get the error: "NameError: name 'js_objs' is not defined". Thanks again.

Comment: edited for clarity. But what I wrote is a shim. You first run the thing you have already, then this will transform the result of that library into what you want.

Comment: Is this not what you wanted, @Stefan?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. This is what I want. Thanks